# VBA Remove Duplicates in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have some issues to remove in an excel sheets my duplicates from a single Column (the first one). When i use the "RemoveDuplicates" function , i got some error " code 1004" . "total" is my worksheet and "rng" is define and set as a Range as you can see here :

```
With total
    Set rng1 = .Range("A2:B" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
    rng1.RemoveDuplicates
```

Comment: As SwedishProgrammer has pointed out - change your RemoveDuplicates row to `rng1.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo` to check both columns for duplicates, or exactly as SwedishProgrammer has put to check just the first column.

Answer (score 2):

I started recording a macro and did the exercise I'm guessing you describe.

It generated the following code:

```
Columns("A:B").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

With the exception that I removed the specific row references, so that it checks the entire column. Is this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
Sub XYZ()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim total As Worksheet
Dim cdLR As Long

Set WB = Workbooks("name_of your_workbook.xlsm")
Set total = WB.Sheets("total")

With total
cdLR = total.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2:B" & cdLR).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1
End With

End Sub
```